# Scale and move drawing using KineticJs

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, kineticjs

I am having trouble getting a drawing to scale properly using KineticJs.  I have a drawing made up of a number of Kinetic drawing objects that are all held in a Group.  What I am attempting to do is to make an adjustment to the length of the drawing and if the new length exceeds a certain threshold then the drawing will be rescaled.

It works well up to this point.  The rescaling is working as expected but I am having issues when it comes to centre the drawing again.  The origin of the drawing is being calculated and I'm trying to move it using

```
    drawingGroup.move(newOrigin.x, newOrigin.y)
```

The initial origin is roughly 200px.  When the drawing begins to be rescaled then this value is 0 but as the image continues to shrink it begins to fall off the left side of the screen.

I haven't come across a good example to adjust the length of a drawing and then scale , resize and centre the new drawing.  Is there a good way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**How to scale down your group to fit on the stage even if the group is made wider**

This illustration shows the starting “blue” group – not widened and not scaled.

[image]

This illustration shows the blue group after it has widened beyond the stage and scaled back.

[image]

**Here’s how to scale down your group without it “floating” left:**

- Undo any previous  group offset (by the amount of any previous scaling factor).
- Calculate the new scaling factor (for example: scale down).
- Save the new scaling factor for use in any future scaling.
- Calculate the new group offset based on the new scaling factor.
- Set the group's offset to the newly scaled offset.
- Redraw the layer.

You will need to add several properties to drawingGroup related to scaling:

```
// the current SCALED offset
drawingGroup.offsetX=0;
drawingGroup.offsetY=0;

// the point from which all scaling will occur
drawingGroup.scalePtX=0;
drawingGroup.scalePtY=0;

// the amount of current scaling applied to the group
// ==1.00 is the beginning un-scaled group
// >1.00 scales the group larger
// <1.00 scales the group smaller
drawingGroup.scaleFactor=1.00;
```

Then add this method to drawingGroup to actually do the scaling:

```
drawingGroup.scaleBy=function(scaleChange){

    // undo previous offset
    this.offsetX += this.scalePtX/this.scaleFactor;
    this.offsetY += this.scalePtY/this.scaleFactor;

    // calc new scaling factor
    var newScaleFactor = this.scaleFactor*(1+scaleChange);

    // create new offset
    this.offsetX -= this.scalePtX/newScaleFactor;
    this.offsetY -= this.scalePtY/newScaleFactor;

    // set new scale factor
    this.scaleFactor=newScaleFactor;

    // do the new offset
    this.setOffset(this.offsetX,this.offsetY);

    // do the new scale
    this.setScale(this.scaleFactor);

    layer.draw();

};
```

This is test code that both widens the group and auto-downscales it to fit the stage:

This test code also recenters the group after downscaling.

```
    // widen by 20px
    // if wider than stage, scale down by 15%
    $("#wider").click(function(){
        drawingGroup.setWidth(drawingGroup.getWidth()+20);
        rect.setWidth(drawingGroup.getWidth());
        var width=drawingGroup.getWidth()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        if(drawingGroup.getX()+width>stageWidth){
            drawingGroup.scaleBy(-0.15);
            recenter();
        }
        setStatus();
        layer.draw();
    });

    function recenter(){
        var w=drawingGroup.getWidth()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        var h=drawingGroup.getHeight()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        drawingGroup.setX(stage.getWidth()/2-w/2);
        drawingGroup.setY(stage.getHeight()/2-h/2);
    }
```

Note that setX()/setY() can be used normally for the group.

Just be sure to calculate the *scaled* group width/height by multiplying by the scalingFactor.

Here is complete code and a Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/UyDbW/

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://d3lp1msu2r81bx.cloudfront.net/kjs/js/lib/kinetic-v4.5.4.min.js"></script>

<style>
body{ padding:15px; }
#container{
  border:solid 1px #ccc;
  margin-top: 10px;
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
}
</style>        
<script>
$(function(){

    var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
      container: 'container',
      width: 300,
      height: 300
    });
    var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
    stage.add(layer);

    // objects used in jquery events
    var drawingGroup;
    var rect,circle;
    var stageWidth=stage.getWidth();
    var stageHeight=stage.getHeight();


    drawingGroup=new Kinetic.Group({
        x:stageWidth/2-50,
        y:stageHeight/2-50,
        width:100,
        height:100,
    });
    drawingGroup.offsetX=0;
    drawingGroup.offsetY=0;
    drawingGroup.scalePtX=0;
    drawingGroup.scalePtY=0;
    drawingGroup.scaleFactor=1.00;
    drawingGroup.scaleBy=function(scaleChange){

        // undo previous offset
        this.offsetX += this.scalePtX/this.scaleFactor;
        this.offsetY += this.scalePtY/this.scaleFactor;

        // calc new scaling factor
        var newScaleFactor = this.scaleFactor*(1+scaleChange);

        // create new offset
        this.offsetX -= this.scalePtX/newScaleFactor;
        this.offsetY -= this.scalePtY/newScaleFactor;

        // set new scale factor
        this.scaleFactor=newScaleFactor;

        // do the new offset
        this.setOffset(this.offsetX,this.offsetY);

        // do the new scale
        this.setScale(this.scaleFactor);

        layer.draw();

    };
    layer.add(drawingGroup);

    var rect=new Kinetic.Rect({
        x:0,
        y:0,
        width:100,
        height:100,
        stroke:"lightgray",
        fill:"skyblue"
    });
    drawingGroup.add(rect);

    var circle=new Kinetic.Circle({
        x:50,
        y:50,
        radius:20,
        fill:"blue"
    });
    drawingGroup.add(circle);

    var status=new Kinetic.Text({
        x:15,
        y:15,
        text:"width=100, scale=1.00",
        fontSize:18,
        fill:"red"
    });
    layer.add(status);

    setStatus();

    layer.draw();

    function setStatus(){
        var width=drawingGroup.getWidth();
        var scale=Math.round(drawingGroup.scaleFactor*100);
        status.setText("Width: "+width+", Scale: "+scale+"%");
    }


    // widen by 20px
    // if wider than stage, scale down by 15%
    $("#wider").click(function(){
        drawingGroup.setWidth(drawingGroup.getWidth()+20);
        rect.setWidth(drawingGroup.getWidth());
        var width=drawingGroup.getWidth()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        if(drawingGroup.getX()+width>stageWidth){
            drawingGroup.scaleBy(-0.15);
            recenter();
        }
        setStatus();
        layer.draw();
    });

    function recenter(){
        var w=drawingGroup.getWidth()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        var h=drawingGroup.getHeight()*drawingGroup.scaleFactor;
        drawingGroup.setX(stage.getWidth()/2-w/2);
        drawingGroup.setY(stage.getHeight()/2-h/2);
    }


}); // end $(function(){});

</script>       
</head>

<body>
    <p>Blue group will scale if extending past stage</p>
    <button id="wider">Wider</button>
    <div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That's close to what I am looking for.  The difference is that each time that the length of the drawing group expands I am trying to recentre the image inside the layer when it is redrawn.  Do you know a good way to do this?

Comment: I edited my answer to recenter the group after it has been down-scaled.  Note that you can use setX/setY normally on the group.  However, getWidth/getHeight will report unscaled values so you must multiply that width/height by drawingGroup's scaleFactor to get the scaled sizes.

Comment: I have an update to this question.  What I would like to do is to adjust the length of the drawing and to rescale the drawing with each increment.  I would like to have the drawing centred on the y-axis but the drawing should be set to 20px from the left side of the stage.  I haven't been able to get the scaling working correctly when using increment/decrement.  Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: I've set up a fiddle that shows what I would like the result to be here http://jsfiddle.net/tctruckscience/rsEyA/15/.  The difference from what I'm currently trying to do is that the drawing is already being scaled before it is drawn.  For example its length is 9900 and the screen size is 1060 so the pixels per scale unit would be 1060/9900 = 0.10707.  However when the image is drawn, the scale is set to 1. If 100 is added to the length of the drawing the calculation is 1060/10000 = 0.106 but I haven't been able to calculate the scale right in this scenario. Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Part 1: you can easily fix the left position of the group by setting its X position to 20 and *not calling recenter* (although you asked me to put recenter in for you! [grin]).  Part 2: I'm not *SURE* what you're asking but if you want to keep the rect at a fixed width, you will need to calc the scaleFactor needed to scale the group width == your desired width (originalWidth/newWidth)...then apply that same scaleFactor to the height.  Note: Since your contents might not be scaling at this "artificially fixed" factor, your contents might fall outside the container rect when scaling larger.

Comment: You are right about Part 1 and your set up for the recentering worked great. Requirements changed and I had to move it closer to the left.  The Fiddle I set up above (jsfiddle.net/tctruckscience/rsEyA/15) did have the drawing set to x=20.  I've set up another question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18963352/using-kineticjs-to-update-and-rescale-a-drawing covering this topic because it isn't exactly related to the initial question I had.